# Copy a specific file (.docx, .pdf, .pptx etc) form folder in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to copy a file (.docx, .pdf, .pptx etc) from a source folder(on server) to a destination folder(on client). 
The user can choose which among the list of files that he wants to download. He selects the files and then downloads it(Copies it to his computer) to the destination path 
`dstnLocation= @"C:\Fldr\Docs;`

My Code:

```
string sourceLocation = textBox2.Text;
string dstnLocation = @"C:\Fldr\Docs";
System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(dstnLocation);
file.Directory.Create();

System.IO.File.Copy(sourceLocation, dstnLocation,true);
MessageBox.Show("Download Complete");
```

The problem is that it creates a file as "Docs"(where one has to use open with to open the file) and if I am not wrong then its because of the destination path. Could someone please tell what all am I doing wrong.
The source path is retrieved through database!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to concat otherwise you're destination location is just the folder not the file path destination

so do something like

```
 var destFile = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", dstnLocation, Path.GetFileName(sourceLocation));
```

then copy that

So code becomes

```
string sourceLocation = textBox2.Text;
string dstnLocation = string.Format(@"C:\Fldr\Docs\{0}", Path.GetFileName(sourceLocation);
if (! System.IO.Directory.Exists(dstnLocation))
{
      System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dstnLocation);
}

System.IO.File.Copy(sourceLocation, dstnLocation,true);
MessageBox.Show("Download Complete");
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot! I had some issues with my system hence took so long to reply!! I tried the about code but now i get an annoying error **access to the path is denied**!

Comment: thats purely permissions on the source file or the destination path. check both ends and make sure whatever user the code is running as has permissions at both ends

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the file name incorrectly:

```
string dstnLocation = @"C:\Fldr\Docs";
System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(dstnLocation);
```

This creates a file with the name `"C:\Fldr\Docs"` for example what you want is `"C:\Fldr\Docs\myfilename.docx"` if I am not mistaken?

Try this instead:

```
var filename = Path.GetFileName(sourceLocation);
string dstnLocation = Path.Combine(@"C:\Fldr\Docs", filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the destination requires an "output" file name.

This problem lies in this line of code

```
System.IO.File.Copy(sourceLocation, dstnLocation,true);
```

The dstnLocation needs to be concatenated with the output file name for example:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(sourceLocation, Path.Combine(dstnLocation,"Database.dbs"),true);
```